# Php curl and serialize problem

Tags: php, serialization, post, curl

In order to pass array variables via my curl script, I am using `serialize` because curl POST elements must not be arrays.

The string that I get after serialization is:

```
a:10:{s:8:"question";s:18:"How are you doing?";s:11:"view_option";s:6:"select";s:10:"txt_answer";a:4:{i:0;s:8:"dsadsdsa";i:1;s:5:"dsads";i:2;s:10:"dsadsdsdsa";i:3;s:0:"";}s:4:"next";s:1:"9";s:7:"bgimage";s:0:"";s:9:"bck_color";s:0:"";s:12:"border_color";s:0:"";s:11:"select_font";s:1:"1";s:9:"font_size";s:4:"12px";s:4:"poll";s:9:"Get Poll!";}
```

Curl makes it:

```
a:10:{s:8:\"question\";s:18:\"How are you doing?\";s:11:\"view_option\";s:6:\"select\";s:10:\"txt_answer\";a:4:{i:0;s:8:\"dsadsdsa\";i:1;s:5:\"dsads\";i:2;s:10:\"dsadsdsdsa\";i:3;s:0:\"\";}s:4:\"next\";s:1:\"9\";s:7:\"bgimage\";s:0:\"\";s:9:\"bck_color\";s:0:\"\";s:12:\"border_color\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"select_font\";s:1:\"1\";s:9:\"font_size\";s:4:\"12px\";s:4:\"poll\";s:9:\"Get Poll!\";}
```

before sending to the server. Above is what I see at the server end. Now, because of the backslashes, above is *not* unserializable.

What do I do now? If I just unescape all quotes - how do I distinguish between escapes put by CURL and escapes that could be part of the data?

---

### EDIT

The error I get when trying to unserialize the escaped string is:

`Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 304 of 351 bytes in /var/www/localserver/test/ser.php on line 8`

thanks

JP

Comment: I avoid sending PHP data serialized and opt for JSON instead.  You may want to try that instead.

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with json, though have used it sometimes to deal with an api (mostly as a mysterious blackbox :)). Do u mean I should try `json_encode` instead of `serialize` with curl or something completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server probably has [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled, which means that your input data is escaped.

Your options are to disable it in your `php.ini` file or to call [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes) on the data when it is received.

Escapes that are part of the data will be double escaped, so unescaping them shouldn't be a problem.

**Disabling in php.ini**

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

**`stripslashes`**

```
$data = stripslashes($_POST['data']);
```

Comment: which server? the proxy server that has curl script or server that curl is making request to?

Comment: also, any idea how to avoid removal of slashes that i dont want. that is - what if the slash is part of data (and not put by server?)

Comment: This solved my problem, and most importantly, my doubt that double escaped things will be preserved (on hindsight, i should have figured that out but sometimes just go blank with a simple problem :)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comments, you may want to try JSON instead.  But, wanted to point out that this works fine for me.

```
<?php

$c = "a:10:{s:8:\"question\";s:18:\"How are you doing?\";s:11:\"view_option\";s:6:\"select\";s:10:\"txt_answer\";a:4:{i:0;s:8:\"dsadsdsa\";i:1;s:5:\"dsads\";i:2;s:10:\"dsadsdsdsa\";i:3;s:0:\"\";}s:4:\"next\";s:1:\"9\";s:7:\"bgimage\";s:0:\"\";s:9:\"bck_color\";s:0:\"\";s:12:\"border_color\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"select_font\";s:1:\"1\";s:9:\"font_size\";s:4:        \"12px\";s:4:\"poll\";s:9:\"Get Poll!\";}";

print_r(unserialize($c));
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [question] => How are you doing?
    [view_option] => select
    [txt_answer] => Array
        (
            [0] => dsadsdsa
            [1] => dsads
            [2] => dsadsdsdsa
            [3] => 
        )

    [next] => 9
    [bgimage] => 
    [bck_color] => 
    [border_color] => 
    [select_font] => 1
    [font_size] => 12px
    [poll] => Get Poll!
)
```

**EDIT**
As mentioned by @lonesomeday, you probably have php magic quotes turned on on the server receiving this data.

Comment: thats strange! let me try to debug why it isnt working for me

Comment: But if you post it to a server which has magic quotes enabled, it will be escaped again, which will render it unusable without filtering through `stripslashes`.

Comment: this is the error I get with the code you posted: `Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 304 of 351 bytes in /var/www/localserver/test/ser.php on line 8`

Comment: @nikc: this time, I am not posting it, but directly using the php script which sberry2A posted (on the remote server in question)